# SQL syntax error, closing bracket expected

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

**I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with this after looking online and trying a few things;**

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (

 PRODID              NUMERIC(6), 

 DESCRIP             CHAR(30),

 CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PRIMARY_KEY KEY)
 ;
```

**i keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.**

Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 127)
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT ( PRODID NUMERIC(6), DESCRIP CHAR(30), 
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PRIMARY_KEY KEY)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY)' at line 4

Comment: Hint:  `CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PRIMARY_KEY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (

 PRODID              NUMERIC(6), 

 DESCRIP             CHAR(30),
 CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (PRODID)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can try It*

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    PRODID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DESCRIP varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODID)
);
```